# Matplotlib Legend string formatting / Align

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to plot a graph with a nicely formatted legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_label ="""\
CL      :1.2565
CM      :1.2565
Tot CD  :1.2565"""

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

foil=[(0, 1), (0, 0), 'black']
ax.plot(*foil, label=test_label)

plt.xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-0.75, 0.75)
plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show(block=False)
```

As you can see the *test_label* is nicely formatted (vertically aligned colons), but this alignment is not preserved when I do the actual plot.

[image: strong text]

Could anyone please suggest a way to place this legend in such a way that all colons are aligned vertically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the font type into `monospace`.

### Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_label ="""\
CL      :1.2565
CM      :1.2565
Tot CD  :1.2565"""

# Change the font type.
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

foil=[(0, 1), (0, 0), 'black']
ax.plot(*foil, label=test_label)

plt.xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-0.75, 0.75)
plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show(block=False)
```

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text justification of the legend to the right so that the numbers have the same number of digits and can be aligned.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_label ="""\
CL      :1.2565
CM      :1.2565
Tot CD  :1.2565"""

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

foil=[(0, 1), (0, 0), 'black']
ax.plot(*foil, label=test_label)

plt.xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-0.75, 0.75)
legend = plt.legend(frameon=False)
for t in legend.get_texts():
    t.set_ha('right')
    
plt.show(block=False)
```

[image]